# Generating a range of numbers according to some rules

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I'm pretty new to Mathematica, and I'm mainly a programmer so I don't have a lot of knowledge about maths.

I want to generate a set of UNIQUE incremental numbers (series) according to the following rules:

- From N1 to N2 INCLUSIVE
- The count is exactly N e.g. I want 5000 numbers
- Scales according to a function i.e. I want the distance between each number and the following number to increase sequentially for example I want it to scale such that the first 25% of the range contains 50% of the number (numbers close together) then next 25% contains 30% of the numbers, then 15% then 5%, that way as you move forward the numbers are stretched further apart.

Thanks,
SM


EDIT: The actual situation that makes me think I need this is:
I'm simulating a slot game where you can win an amount of money each spin, I get a long list of all the wins and their frequencies, now I want to **"redistribute"** or **"group up"** those range of wins into a smaller set, for example only 5000 numbers instead of having like 1M, I want to do that by basically generating a series as specified in my question and then "grouping" each of the real wins into the closest number in the generated set, so for example 0.9, 1 and 1.1 would be grouped into just 1 with frequency 3 (assuming that 1 is in the generated set of numbers)

EDIT:
**Now that my question has been answered, my next step should be:**

1. My new set of numbers has a weights list all initialised to 0 {0,0,0,...}
2. Go through my original list and for each number I get its weight and add it to the weight of the nearest number in the new set.
   For example:
   Original: {1,2,3,4,5,...,10} (from 1 to 10)
   Weights: {1,1,1,1,..} (all have equal weight)
   New set: {1,10}
   so the weights for the new set would be calculated:
   {1 to 5} get "rounded" to 1 (closest number)
   {6 to 10} get "rounded" to 10 (closest number)
   New weights: {5,5}

I can do this in code easily but I'm sure there must be a way to do this in Mathematica? Should I post this as a new question? I don't want to spam

Comment: As a first start you could write one function as `Piecewise` spreading your values over your Range N. Just in case: Rule of Thumb - never use `For`- loops

Comment: Thanks that's quite useful actually

Comment: On second thought: What do you intend to use this list for? Since you said you are new to Mathematica, it could well be that there is a build-in function for what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question

Comment: I am a bit occupied at the moment, but my first guess for solving your problem would be `GatherBy` or `BinCount`, or `BinList` - depending on what exactly your output should look like.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might put you on track. Say your range is 1 to 50000. We can weight these in quartiles so that the first ones have 50% chance of being selected, 30% for the ones in the next quartile, etc. Then form a random sample without duplication using weighted RandomSample. Last sort so the result is ascending. Below is the code for this.

```
n = 50000;
rng = Range[n];
wts = Join[ConstantArray[1, n/4], ConstantArray[6/10, n/4], 
   ConstantArray[3/10, n/4], ConstantArray[1/10, n/4]];

SeedRandom[1111];
sample = Sort[RandomSample[wts -> rng, 5000]];
```

To check the quality I'll bin into quartiles, then find the length of each bin.

```
lens = Map[Length, BinLists[sample, n/4]]

(* Out[25]= {2474, 1505, 773, 248} *)
```

Let's get the respective fractions.

```
N[lens/5000]

(* Out[26]= {0.4948, 0.301, 0.1546, 0.0496} *)
```

Comment: very interesting answer, it seems to solve my problem I need to do some checks to be sure though, cheers for that

Comment: yup that's what I needed. In my case I already have the weight for each number in the original list.

Answer (score 3):

Here is approach that doesn't rely on random numbers but instead generates a completely deterministic sequence of numbers that tracks the desired distribution optimally.

The distribution given in the example can be written like this, assuming all numbers are in percent:

```
ρ[x_] := Piecewise[{
           {50, 0 <= x < 25}, 
           {30, 25 <= x < 50}, 
           {15, 50 <= x < 75}, 
           {5, 75 < x <= 100}
         }]
Plot[ρ[x], {x, 0, 100}, Exclusions -> None, 
      AxesLabel -> {x, ρ}, BaseStyle -> Larger]
```

[image: rho]

Now I generate the desired numbers in a list called `spacedOut`, with a length of `5000` entries:

```
numberOfValues = 5000;
max = Integrate[ρ[x1], {x1, 0, 100}];
dx = max/numberOfValues;

spacedOut = 
  Most@Rest@NestWhileList[(# + dx/N[ρ[#]]) &, 0, (# <= 100) &];

ListPlot[spacedOut]
```

[image: spaced]

To check that we got the desired result, look at the number of values and their percent distribution:

```
Length[spacedOut] == numberOfValues
(* ==> True *)

100 BinCounts[spacedOut, {0, 100, 25}]/Length[spacedOut] // N
(* ==> {49.98, 30.02, 15., 5.} *)
```

The last line shows that the distribution is spot on, *without* having to rely on the law of large numbers in a random process.

Basically what I did in the `NestWhileList` was to construct the inverse of the integrated distribution in a discretized form. Or in other words, I used the relation $\Delta y = \rho(x) \Delta x$ where $x$ is in the interval $[0,100]$ and let $y$ increase in constant steps to calculate successive values of the corresponding $x$. The total number of steps is predetermined by calculating the integral of $\rho$ over the whole interval $[0,100]$ and adjusting the step width `dx` accordingly.

Therefore, the values in `spacedOut` will all lie between $0$ and $100$, but with a varying spacing to create the correct distribution.

The final step is to uniformly rescale and shift all the numbers in `spacedOut` so that its minimum and maximum agree with the minimum and maximum values `n1` and `n2` that you want:

```
n1 = 17; n2 = 511;
final = n1 + spacedOut*(n2 - n1)/100
```

This approach doesn't require a piecewise constant distribution. The function $\rho(x)$ can be an arbitrary distribution.

Comment: ha, I learned some new things by trying to understand your answer, still don't fully understand it to be honest (the Δy=ρ(x)Δx par), but thanks that was quite useful